# What is better/shorter phrase "phone is on blacklist" or "phone is blacklisted"?

Tags: phrase-usage

I found two different translations for this phrase. Which is more correct, or is more commonly used by native speakers?

1. *That phone is on the blacklist.*
2. *That phone is blacklisted.*

Context: I wish to say that a particular phone is listed somewhere as the phone of someone engaged in wrongdoing such as fraud.

Comment: The phone *is blacklisted* or *is on the black list*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second is probably more common but is still a little awkard.  It is not the physical phone that is blacklisted, but the phone number.  Therefor,  most common would probably be

> That phone number is blacklisted.

Answer (score 3):

The better and shorter phrase is #2

> **That phone is blacklisted**.